# ASP.Net @ Symbol

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to follow some tutorials for ASP.Net and for the life of me, I just can't figure out what the `@` Symbol does when it is before an variable.

I thought it was just a shortcut to either session variables or request.form, but I have tried it in a few places without any luck.

When I put it in somewhere at random, I get the error : `Expression Expected`, however, when I look at the examples I am working from, they do not look like expressions so I am very confused!

Please help!?

Comment: Please show an example of what you mean.

Comment: There are a few of them. Look in the MSDN ASP.NET markup reference.

Comment: I recommend people stop answering the question until noob2 tells us which "@" he's talking about. We've got three answers already, and they might all be wrong.

Comment: I have seen it everywhere, books (even beginner ones, without an explanation), MSDN, other code example sites.... in particular, right now I am looking at http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-08-vb.aspx (scroll to bottom, last code example)... I just see @ symbols in so many places and other than in email addresses, I have no idea what they mean!

Comment: Please, show a specific example, in your actual question. There are so many uses of "@" that it's not possible to answer you.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question, since you can't be bothered to be more specific. Also -1 for lack of clarity. Next, you'll no doubt ask about the use of "%".

Comment: I didn't think it was that vague - and I put the example in comments here, and everyone who answered knew exactly what I meant - and I have an answer I want... All three answers are good and I have learnt a lot... I know what the % symbol means (well, in most palces!)!

Comment: The fact that you got three totally-different answers proves that your question was very vague. The example you gave in the comments (don't do that, BTW, edit your question instead) is in a different programming language!

Comment: Edit your actual question to show what you're asking about, and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I did write exactly what I wanted to know "@ symbol before a variable" the three answers both cover exactly what I wanted to know - sorry if you did not read the question fully, but other people have and they have answered it fine. I asked what I wanted to know and other people have answered. The three questions are not different, they all cover strings/variable and I am happy... It seems that you just did not read/understand properly.

Comment: Does the answer by solairaja answer your question? There's no "@" before a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@` symbol in C# allows you to use a keyword as a variable name.

For instance:

```
//this will throw an exception, in C# class is a keyword
string class = "CSS class name"; 

//this won't
string @class = "CSS class name";
```

Usually it's best to avoid using keywords as variable names, but sometimes it's more elegant than having awkward variable names. You tend to most often see them when serialising stuff for the web and in anon types.

Your error is probably due to applying the `@` before a variable name that isn't a keyword.

**Update:**

In T-SQL `@` is always used before parameter names, for instance:

```
select * 
from [mytable]
where [mytable].[recId] = @id
```

You would then specify the @id parameter when you called the query.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you wrote, makes sense so +1 - but also, why is it that http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-08-vb.aspx (Scroll down to the bottom for last code example), almost every variable has an @ symbol, even when it doesn't look like they are declaring anything?

Comment: @noob2: please update your question to include a short example of what you're talking about.

Comment: In that think they're using `@` because SQL server does that before all parameters. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wording: It won't throw an exception but a compiler error, right?

Comment: @noob2: did you notice that the example you're referring to is in VB.NET, not C#?

Comment: Yes, but it still answers the question fine - it is an asp.net issue and not really a c# or vb.net issue.

Comment: It's actually an ADO.NET issue -- and when adding parameters the `@` is optional in most cases (not in the T-SQL string).

Answer (score 7):

There are several different uses for the @ symbol, depending where it is.

In front of a variable name, it allows you to use a reserved word as a variable name:

```
string @string = "a string variable named string";
```

This is not good practice as it can be very confusing when reading code.

In front of a string, it is called a *verbatim string literal* and means that you do not need to escape slashes and such:

```
string path = @"c:\my path\is here";
string normal_path = "c:\\my path\\is here";
```

Answer (score 5):

In ASPX page, @ symbol is used along with the page directives.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

In the Code page, @ Symbol is used for the string values escape characters.

```
String s = @"c:/Document/Files/Sample.txt"
```