# ASP.NET MVC Razor rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does the following code renders my child action:

```
<div class='h-l'>
  @if (ViewBag.Hide)
  {
     @Html.Action(MVC.City.GetCitiesList().AddRouteValue("makeBig", false));
  }
</div>
```

but if I delete @ before `@Html.Action`, nothing is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703572.aspx)

> ChildActionExtensions.Action Method. 
> Invokes a child action method and returns the result as an HTML string.

You should use `@` to determine a string as a method. Take a look at [ASP.Net @ Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906935/asp-net-symbol)

Comment: The reason is because you can use html tags in a code block. And you can insert strings inside them. Thus any command without @ will be determined as a simple string.

Comment: Shymep, but why then it doesn't render this "string" in case I don't type @?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't succeeded in finding an article on MDSN describing rendering inside code blocks. Seems exactly @ answers for rendering. Otherwise it's just a command (if not inside a tag block).